# sphinx to document QGIS plugin

Tags: qgis, python, qgis-plugins

I am trying to document a code for a QGIS plugin. I have installed sphinx in anaconda. When I try do make html, i get an error saying "No module named 'qgis'", I belive it comes from one of the classes trying to import qgis.core. I have read suggestions to use OSGeo4W to install QGIS as it would give me all the enviroment there. However, when i try to import qgis.core within that shell it still cant fin qgis module. I have also faild to install sphinx in OSGeo through pip.

So my question is, how can I use sphinx to document a QGIS plugin code?

I am using anaconda 5.1, python 3.6.5 and sphinx 1.7.2

Comment: If you failed to install sphinx in OSGeo through pip, and, Sphinx can't find your modules then you haven't set up your environment properly.  For example check: http://spatialgalaxy.net/2014/10/09/a-quick-guide-to-getting-started-with-pyqgis-on-windows/

Comment: Have you done what you intended for? I see the plugin authored by @Kasper. It appears that you have sorted out the documentation issue (https://github.com/KaspArno/Tilgjengelighet/tree/master/FAKT_Dokumentasjon). Could you please explain how you solved your problem?

Comment: @banbar Hi, I am sorry I don't quite remember, but I think I just removed/commented the imports it wouldn't document before I ran the program